# Laravel: Can I use Redirect::intended in filters other than authentication filter?

Tags: php, laravel

This section about [Authenticating Users](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) on Laravel Docs say that:

> The Redirect::intended function will redirect the user to the URL they were trying to access before being caught by the authentication filter.

Can I use it with other filters?

```
Route::filter('auth_role_set', function()
{
    if (! Session::has('auth_role')) return Redirect::to('roles');
});
```

and in a controller:

```
public function roles()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $roles = explode(',', $user->roles);

    if (count($roles) == 1)
    {
        Session::put('auth_role', $user->roles);
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it and see what happens! Worst case scenario is that it doesn't do what you want. I'm not sure exactly what you'd need it for, though?

Comment: It does not work for me. So, I want to know if someone know whether it works or I have made any mistake.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're adding an extra redirect. After the first redirect happens, the session is cleared and there is nothing on `url.intended` for the second request. You can keep the data in session calling `Session::keep('url.intended')` before the first redirection.

Comment: @Raphael_ When does Laravel set `url.intended` in the session? Does it happen only before being caught by the authentication filter.

Comment: Oh, my bad. My first comment was kinda wrong. Laravel sets `url.intended` in session when you call `Redirect::guest()`. Try using that on the filter, instead of `Redirect::to()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Raphael_ already mentioned, you need theese steps to make use of `Redirect::intended()`:

- in your **filters.php** redirect the user to your role-setting-page using `Redirect::guest('/role')`
- in your **controller** use `Redirect::intended('/fallback-url')`

in the end the user will be at the first page, where the `/role` redirection started.